# SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail

I have this issue on my website 2 weeks after hosting it on aws lightsail, the error is : " SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE " on safari and firefox browsers, it is working fine on google chrome.
i tried to install a new certificate from lightsail but still didn't work, i hope to find a solution because my visitors can't access my website.
https://mondoc.pro/

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It says it's revoked in my instance of Chrome. Maybe it's actually been revoked.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mondoc.pro) the certificate for your site is revoked, i.e. Firefox is correct:

[image]

For why some browsers say its revoked while others not: the revocation checks in browsers are unfortunately spotty. For more on this see [How well do current browsers handle certificate revocation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219443/how-well-do-current-browsers-handle-certificate-revocation) and [How Do Browsers Handle Revoked SSL/TLS Certificates?](https://www.ssl.com/blogs/how-do-browsers-handle-revoked-ssl-tls-certificates/).